# Large unused area in visual studio code on right

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VSC for the first time and I'm confused by the ruler in the code. Will it prevent me from writing past it? If so, then it seems like there's a huge unused area in the window.

I was able to remove the minimap, but I still cannot find a way to remove this huge unused space, can any one suggest how to get rid of it [image]

Comment: That space is part of the window. What do you expect? What do you want to replace it with? Do you want to change your line-wrapping settings to make your code lines longer? Why not just resize your window like you can with any other window in your desktop environment? Or do you want the editor to be centered? You can get a centered layout by default in zen-mode (`View > Appearance > Zen Mode`).

Comment: I want the whole space to be used by code , so I have more area to code

Comment: well, you have no code to fill that space with. What do you want us to tell you? To arbitrarily add code to fill that space? I'm quite confused. You could... open split editor groups to fill the space I suppose. (open a new file and drag its tab handle to create new editor group, or click the "split editor right" button at the top left of the tab handle bar)

Comment: ok , totally my mistake, I thought that the line was a divider , been using Xcode, so got confused, I can actually write beyond it as well, sorry , I will delete the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is just a visual guide. See the `editor.rulers` setting.

It doesn't necessasrily wrap lines when you start to write past it, unless you also do `"editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn"` and set `"editor.wordWrapColumn"` to something.

Comment: agreed , I got confused as its very similar to the divider line for terminal panel